# import, export and other es6 features not working when I choose express as integrated server-side framework in nuxt?

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6, nuxt.js

While installing nuxtjs using the following command as described in the documentation [here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/installation)

```
$ npx create-nuxt-app <project-name>
```

It will ask some questions:

1. Choose between integrated server-side frameworks:

   - None (Nuxt default server)
   - Express
   - Koa
   - Hapi
   - Feathers
   - Micro
   - Fastify
   - Adonis (WIP)

I choosed `express` and completed my installation. But I can't use `import` `export` and other es6 features inside `nuxt.config.js`.

in there documentation [here](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-hooks#redirect-to-router-base-when-not-on-root) the codes use `import` and `export default`

```
import hooks from './hooks'
export default {
  router: {
    base: '/portal'
  }
  hooks: hooks(this)
}
```

If I choose `None (Nuxt default server)` these codes works fine.
I am working on a front-end application, Back-end is independent node application.  What is the difference between these `integrated server-side frameworks` ? How enable es6 in nuxt config?

Comment: Asking for opinions is not allowed.

Comment: @Gander Am a beginner to nuxt, In there documentation most of the places use  import/export but when I choose this it will fail to work. I want to know the difference.

Comment: Then you asked the wrong question. Write the question differently: provide installed components and an example of code that does not work for you, also describe the steps taken to solve the problem. Describe everything you've done so far.

Comment: Sorry for making confusion on this and Thank you @Gander I will update the question.